# Each file on my external SSD occupies at least 1MB, no matter how small. How can I change this?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, ssd, block-device

I have a Sandisk USB SSD connected to a server (I don't know the exact model and I can't find it from `lsusb -v`).
Whenever I create a file of nonzero size, it occupies 1M space according to `du`.

```
$ echo "foobar" > test
$ du -h test
1.0M    test
$ du --apparent-size -h test
7   test
```

I've read that this has to do with block sizes of the device, but also that block sizes are usually 4096 bytes or some such, not 1 MB. I'm writing many files to the disk which are much smaller, so 90% of space is wasted.

The output of `fdisk` is

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204140544 bytes, 1953523712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x007fa07a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I am not sure how to parse this; does it mean it is NTFS-formatted? `df -T` reports it as `fuseblk`.

Is this just a matter of formatting the drive? Can a block size be selected or is it always determined by the hardware?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is the *allocation unit size* of the filesystem, which may also be called *block size* at the filesystem level. But that is not necessarily the same thing as the block size used at the hardware device level, although the allocation unit size should definitely be some exact multiple of the hardware block size or else there will be inefficiency.

For Linux, the filesystem type indicated by the partition table means nothing; the type is autodetected by inspecting the data actually inside the partition. But for other operating systems, having the filesystem type correctly indicated in the partition table may be helpful.

The `fuseblk` indicates the filesystem is handled by a FUSE user-space filesystem driver; unfortunately FUSE drivers exist both for NTFS (`ntfs-3g`) and exFAT, so it is not very helpful here. At least in Debian/Ubuntu, you might run `pgrep -a mount`: if the output looks like

```
<process ID> /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 <mountpoint of the filesystem> -o <some options>
```

then it is being handled by the `ntfs-3g` driver and is obviously NTFS. An output line for exFAT should include `/sbin/mount.exfat-fuse` or something similar (I don't have an actual exFAT filesystem at hand for testing right now).

Having said that, even exFAT should not be using an allocation unit size of 1 MB unless specified so at filesystem creation time: [according to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat), the default exFAT allocation unit size for a disk of greater than 32 GB should be 128 KB.